# perl smtp datasend

Tags: perl

I'm testing a program that I'm writing in perl to send automated emails by sending them to myself first and I am noticing that all the carriage returns and tabs (\n and \t) that I am putting in the emails are turning up in outlook as spaces when I read the emails.  Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 2):

"\n" is a unix end of line
i think you need to use "\r\n" for windows

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Outlook to discard the extra lines. The alert is hard to see in the message. It should be above the From line when you double-click and open the message.

It should say something like **"Extra line breaks in this message were removed -> Restore line breaks"**

To prevent this problem, try formatting your lines with a carriage return and line feed (`\r\n`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would advise avoiding tab (\t) characters in email messages; there's no standardization among email clients controlling how they're displayed.